# Full subcategory of Ab isn't abelian

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I have to prove this exercise:

Recall that an abelian group $A$ is divisible if , for any $a \in A$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the equation $nx=a$ has a solution in $A$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the full subcategory of $Ab$ consisting of the divisible abelian groups. Show that $\mathcal{D}$ is pre-abelian but not abelian with the hint: Show that the quotient map $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a bimorphism but not an isomorphism in $\mathcal{D}$.

I proved that $\mathcal{D}$ is a pre-additive category, in fact product and coproduct in $\mathcal{D}$ are the same product and coproduct in $Ab$. Now I have to prove that for every morphism $f$ in $\mathcal{D}$ exists kernel and cokernel. After that, I know that in an abelian category bimorphism and isomorphism are the same thing, so if I found a bimorphism in $\mathcal{D}$ such that it isn't an isomorphism in $\mathcal{D}$ the exercises is finished. This morphism is the quotient map in the hint. Call this map $\pi$. I have a doubt, obviously $\pi$ isn't an isomorphism since it isn't invertible. It is an epimorphism since it is surjective, but why is it a monomorphism? I have to use the property of divisible abelian group , but how?

If I take $h,g:A \to \mathbb{Q}$(with $A \in Ob \mathcal{D}$) such that $fh=gh$ then
$$\forall a \in A \quad h(a)-g(a) \in \mathbb{Z}$$
and now we can use that
$\forall b \in A$ the equation
$$(h(a)-g(a))x=b$$
have a solution in $A$. After that I don't know how I can conclude.

ideas?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138189/full-subcategories-of-mathsfgrp-with-epis-monos-which-are-not-surjective-in), how to show that this quotient map is a bihomomorphism but not an isomorphism in this category.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949728/the-category-of-divisible-abelian-groups-pi-mathbbq-rightarrow-frac-mat):"Therefore, this shows that the category of divisible abelian groups is not an abelian category. "

Answer (score 0):

Let $\quad h(a)-g(a) = n$. We know that for any $k$ there is $a_k \in A$ which is equal to $a/k$ . So $n =kh(a_k) - kg(a_k)$ is divisible by $k$. The only integer divisible by all $k$ is $0$.